# Nouveaux motifs de clôture — New close reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Des [changements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185088/the-default-off-topic-close-reason-cannot-be-selected-from-the-new-close-dialo/185101#185101) vont intervenir dans les [motifs de clôture](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) d'ici quelques jours :

- « *not constructive* » et « *not a real question* » sont remplacés par :

  - « *unclear what you’re asking* » : pas clair
  - « *too broad* » : trop ambitieux
  - « *primarily opinion-based* » : trop subjectif
- *off-topic* et *too localized* sont remplacés par :

  - jusqu'à 3 sous-raisons propres au site, que nous pouvons choisir ;
  - la migration vers le site méta ;
  - un commentaire choisi librement par la personne qui vote pour clore, qui peut faire de 88 à 600 caractères avec un préfixe suggéré « *This question appears to be off-topic because it is about* » (en anglais, il faudra donc ajouter 30 caractères au moins).
- « *off-topic* » (hors sujet) peut être raffiné par des sous-raisons prédéfinies (3 maximum) ou un commentaire dans un champ libre. Ces sous-raisons peuvent couvrir des cas fréquents qui ne sont pas évidents d'après le nom du site ou l'utilisation qui était jusqu'à présent faite de « *too localized* », qui disparaît.

  Je répète : **[si nous définissons des sous-raisons de « *off-topic* », le « *off-topic* » nu disparaît !](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185088/the-default-off-topic-close-reason-cannot-be-selected-from-the-new-close-dialo/185101#185101)**
- Les questions closes sont marquées comme « *on hold* » (en attente) pendant 5 jours, et « *closed* » ensuite.

Les détails des changements sont [décrits sur le site méta principal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-the-loop-the-closing-overhaul-is-live).

Souhaitons-nous des motifs de clôture locaux prédéfinis sur ce site ?

---

There will be [changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185088/the-default-off-topic-close-reason-cannot-be-selected-from-the-new-close-dialo/185101#185101) in [close reasons](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) in the next few days:

- “not constructive” and “not a real question” are replaced by

  - “unclear what you're asking”
  - “too broad”
  - “primarily opinion-based”
- “off-topic” and “too localized” are replaced by

  - up to 3 site-specific close reasons which will appear as a subheading of “off-topic”;
  - “off-topic” with a free-form comment that must be at least 88 characters long (the prefix “This question appears to be off-topic because it is about ” is pre-entered, so you have to add at least 30 characters);
  - migration (only to meta as long as the site is in beta).

  I repeat: **[per-site off-topic reasons REPLACE plain off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185088/the-default-off-topic-close-reason-cannot-be-selected-from-the-new-close-dialo/185101#185101)**!
- Closed questions will be labeled as “on hold” for 5 days, and “closed” afterwards.

Should we have predefined custom close reasons?

Answer (score 6):

I would definitely add something about proofreading.

- *proofreading*
  We can help you find the correct way to express a single sentence, but we are not a correction center. We can provide insight about correct French usage/grammar for a sentence but we will not correct a whole text.

Comment: “We can provide insight about (…) a sentence but not (…) a whole text.” In other words, the question is *too broad*. We don't need another close reason for this.

Comment: @Gilles Ill need to reread the new too broad, but thing is I think it's way more easier for newusers to understand a "off topic ->proofreading" than a *broad* too broad closure.

Comment: @Gilles I don't think "Too broad" really covers it well enough. It's definitely off-topic imo, and I agree with Hugo on the new user friendliness of this custom reason. Rereading the new "Too broad" description from MSO, it says "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format." Answers wouldn't really be too long, and setting aside reformulations of original text, there are only so many ways to correct spelling mistakes.

Comment: I know we only have three custom slots to begin with, so if leaving one open is desirable in case of future specific problems that we want a custom close reason for, I personally wouldn't mind integrating proofreading to the translation request reason.

Answer (score 4):

Il y a deux types assez courants de questions que nous [rejetons](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) : les demandes de traduction, et les questions dont la réponse se trouvent dans un dictionnaire. Je propose donc les motifs de clôture ci-dessous : *demande de traduction*, et *consulter un dictionnaire* (formulations ci-dessous reprises de la [FAQ](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) avec quelques ajustements mineurs). Avec un hors sujet basique, nous atteignons notre quota de sous-motifs.

---

There are two common kinds of questions that we [reject](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): translation requests and dictionary lookups. I therefore propose the two custom sub-reasons below (wording adapted from the [FAQ](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). That, in addition to plain off-topic, would fill our quota of off-topic sub-reasons.

---

- *translation request / demande de traduction*
  We know French, not other languages. You can ask about the meaning of a difficult French sentence, or how to express an idea in idiomatic French. But please DO NOT ask us to translate a text to or from another language.
  Vous pouvez demander comment exprimer une idée en français, ou une explication d'une phrase difficile. Mais la traduction en tant que telle de ou vers une autre langue est hors sujet.
- *general reference*
  Please look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. If you did so and found nothing satisfactory, mention that in your question. Do give context for where you heard or saw the word.
- *off-topic*
  Questions on French Language & Usage are expected to relate to the French language.
  Les questions sur le site « French Language & Usage » doivent avoir un rapport avec la langue française.

Comment: I agree, though I might suggest we also add proofreading requests? Although those are questions solely about French, it's just not what we do.

Comment: @Kareen Isn't “too broad” enough?

Comment: Consolidating comments on Hugo's answer.

Comment: @Kareen It turns out that plain off-topic will disappear if we have custom reasons — I've updated the announcement. I believe we still need “unrelated to the French language” (e.g. for questions about French culture), so that only leaves two custom sub-reasons.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: I suggest the following.

> - **Translation or proofreading request** — French Language & Usage is not a translation or proofreading service. Only questions about translation to French of short difficult entities such as expressions are accepted, provided that the meaning of the expression is explained.
> - **General reference** — This question can be definitely and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.

---

Compte tenu qu'il y aura une option libre en plus des motifs sur mesure prédéfinis, je crois que les nouveaux motifs de clôture doivent être centrés autour des motifs hors sujet que nous avons eus à ce jour, c'est-à-dire les demandes de traduction ou de correction et les consultations de dictionnaire.

*(L'option libre consiste à permettre aux voteurs d'écrire une raison pour la clôture de la question, par exemple « Cette question semble porter sur les chats, ce qui est hors sujet sur StackOverflow. » Ces raisons seront publiées en tant que commentaires, et le dialogue de clôture y renverra. Les voteurs subséquents auront par la suite ce nouveau motif dans la liste des motifs prédéfinis pour cette question.)*

Depuis le 1<sup>er</sup> janvier 2013, nous avons eu 15 questions closes sous les motifs *off-topic* et *too localized*. Nous avons eu 2 demandes de traduction, 3 demandes de correction, 5 consultations de dictionnaire et 4 catégorie autre. Ces 4 « autres » étaient [Adjectif qualifiant le mot « question » en référence à une estimation](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6213/217), [Can you guess what the correct phrase is?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/5929/217), [Example of using “devoir” in passé composé?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/5887/217) et [Pourquoi « quinze jours d'attentes » avec un « s » à la fin ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/5735/217). Il n'y avait qu'une seule question qui ne touchait pas à la langue française, alors je ne crois pas que ce motif devrait avoir son propre motif prédéfini (l'option libre serait suffisante). Ces questions ont peu en common, mais elles sont presque toutes *too localized*.

Puisque *Too Localized* disparaîtra également en raison des nouveaux motifs de clôture, je suis d'avis que notre troisième motif devrait tenter d'aborder ce type de questions. Je ne sais cependant comment l'aborder pour l'instant.

Je suggère donc d'avoir un motif pour les demandes de traduction et de correction ainsi que pour les question de référence générale et de laisser le troisième pour une solution à *too localized*.

---

Considering that there will be a free-form option in addition to canned custom off-topic reasons, I think the custom reasons need to be focused on the most common off-topic close reasons we've had so far, namely translation/proofreading requests and dictionary look-ups.

*(The free-form option will let closers type in a reason for the close, for example "Your question appears to be about 'Cat Grooming', which is off-topic for Stack Overflow." These reasons will be posted as comments and linked to in the close dialog. Subsequent close-voters will then have that extra reason in the canned close reason list for that question.)*

Since January 1, 2013, we had 15 off-topic and too localized closes. We had 3 translation requests, 3 proofreading requests, 5 dictionary look-ups and 4 others. These 4 others were  [Adjectif qualifiant le mot « question » en référence à une estimation](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6213/217), [Can you guess what the correct phrase is?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/5929/217), [Example of using “devoir” in passé composé?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/5887/217) and [Pourquoi « quinze jours d'attentes » avec un « s » à la fin ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/5735/217). There was only one question not about the French language, so I don't think that reason warrants a custom reason of its own (free-form would be sufficient). They don't have much in common, except they're mostly too localized.

Since *Too Localized* will also disappear because of the new custom close reasons, I feel like our third close reason should try to address these too localized questions. I however do not currently have any idea how to address it.

I therefore suggest having close reasons for translation/proofreading requests and general reference questions, and leave the third one for a potential "too localized" address.

> - **Translation or proofreading request** — French Language & Usage is not a translation or proofreading service. Only questions about translation to French of short difficult entities such as expressions are accepted, provided that the meaning of the expression is explained.
> - **General reference** — This question can be definitely and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I agree with your second comment - edited. As for the first, I was thinking of questions like these ([1](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/6370/217), [2](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/6353/217), [3](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/6357/217)). I understand what you're saying, that's kind of why I said "difficult" entities. But if you think it would still cover these kinds of questions without the "or smaller", then I can remove it.

Comment: Those question are indeed to be accepted, but the *such as* phrasing adds a fair amount of blurriness, and in my opinion, it wouldn't discourage one to ask such questions.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Fair enough.