# Why haven't we rolled out custom close reasons?

Tags: support, status-completed, close-reasons

Custom close reasons have been out for a while now and despite [this discussion](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/217), we still don't have even one (which I noticed after voting to close [this proofreading request question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7072/217)).

From what I understand, mods can edit these custom reasons fairly easily. Is there a reason they haven't been implemented yet? Can we go ahead and implement them?

Comment: 4 vs. 2 vs. 3 as of now, it is a bit short for a consensus. Yet it has been more than a month, so I will add the close reasons suggested by Gilles with a mention of proofreading in translation request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting up close reasons isn't that trivial. You need one mod to propose a reason and one mod to approve. Reasons cannot be edited at all once they are live. Any mod can disable a reason, and two mods can add a new reason, but it gets confusing if there are pending close votes and it makes it harder to track their use.

We have a pretty low volume, so it's difficult to figure out what we really need: we lack statistically significant samples. We need close reasons for common, well-established kinds of questions that we reject. [Your analysis](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/nouveaux-motifs-de-cloture-new-close-reasons/438#438) helped a lot though.

[Evpok has proposed two close reasons, for translation/proofreading requests and  for dictionary lookups](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/why-havent-we-rolled-out-custom-close-reasons#comment868_459). Thanks, Evpok. I've approved them, so they are now live.

---

Nous disposons maintenant de deux motifs de clôture sous « *off-topic* » :

- > French Language & Usage is not a text translation or proofreading service. Questions about translation from French to another language and translations and proofreading of whole texts are off-topic.

  Ce site n'est pas un service de traduction ou de relecture. Les questions portant sur la traduction du français vers une autre langue sont hors-sujet, ainsi que les demandes de traduction ou de relecture d'un texte complet.
- > Please look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. If you did so and found nothing satisfactory, mention that in your question. Do give context for where you heard or saw the word.

  Pour le sens d'un mot ou d'une expression, merci de consulter d'abord un dictionnaire. Si vous l'avez fait et que cela n'a pas répondu à votre question, mentionnez-le dans votre message. Pensez à préciser le contexte dans lequel vous avez vu ou entendu le mot.

Comment: Great, thanks to both of you, and thanks for the clarification on the process!